# Wordpress admin loading cached versions

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, genesis

Just installed Wordpress 4.2.4 on a new database, and am having some caching trouble.

Throughout the whole Wordpress admin (including adding/editing pages, posts, plugins), everything seems to be loading a cached version first. When I refresh, the file in question updates to the actual, most recently saved version.

As a developer, I am able to avoid it by turning my browser caching off or doing a full refresh with emptying the cache whenever I make a change. However, for clients, who will not know about turning caching off, this is not acceptable and can cause a lot of damage to the site. For instance, when I "Add New" page/post, the forms for title and content will display as empty (as they should). When I fill it with content and click "Publish," it now overwrites the last page/post I had published. Only if I reload the page before publishing a new post (despite the title/content fields being blank), will it truly create a new post.

It has been happening prior to the installation of any plugins, and if it factors in at all, I am using a modified child theme for Genesis.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins?

Comment: None, and it was happening even before any plugins were installed.

Comment: sounds like the server is sending expires headers on the admin pages, check your htaccess file or apache.conf, sites-enabled or nginx etc or whatever is relevant

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't see anything about expires headers in the htaccess file-- I did just try doing the same test on another computer and it worked, then went back to my original computer and it worked. Will keep an eye out for an expires header if this happens again though.

This was happening as I was editing within 48 hours of creating the site (subdomain creation and wordpress installation). Could it have had to do with the whole "48 hours for domain changes to take effect?"

Comment: @David Your comment helped me. For those running IIS - the Output Caching module may be caching your .php files to cause this issue.